# Detect if user has put tracking code in place

Tags: javascript

A number of web applications, such as, Clicky and Crazy Egg, require that you put tracking code on your website. Those applications generally detect whether the code has been put in place, but I was wondering  What is the recommended approach (or a approach) is to detect whether a user has put a piece of JavaScript on their website.

**For your information, this question does not refer to any of those applications. I would like to mimic this behavior to let the user know whether the JavaScript snippet has been installed correctly.**

**Edit:** I should have clarified that I would like to detect server-side whether a user has correctly installed the tracking code on their website.

Comment: I would like to detect it server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Check the [HTTP Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

#### Long answer

You need to ensure two things:

- The script file is loaded on the respective page
- The script is actually executed

When a script is included in a page, the browser sets the Referer field's content to that page's URL.

However, this is not reliable. If a user wants to intentionally trick the system, there are ways to load a script file without running it. For example

```
<img src="script.js">
```

This will result in an error, but only after the file is loaded.

If you want to make sure the script is actually run, you may need some type of token injection:

```
// script.js.php
var tokenId = '<?php echo getTokenId(); ?>';
(new Image()).src = 'yesItActuallyRuns.php?tokenId=' + tokenId;
```

There may be other ways, but I can't think of any reliable ones at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Put in a jquery code to find a .js script when the page loads.

Comment: I should have clarified that I would like to detect server-side whether a user has correctly installed the tracking code on their website.

Comment: Even without @BartJacobs's comment above, this is a terrible "answer". jQuery is a huge library with many different features. You need to be much more specific about how to use it to solve the problem.